# (Windows) Batch File for concatenating files

Tags: windows, batch-file, concatenation, batch-processing

I have a folder which contains a hierarchy of subfolders. The subfolders at the lowest level contains files.

Now, I'm interested in a .bat file (for Windows) which takes all files of a specific name, e.g. test.log, in the folder hiearchy and concatenates them and makes a new file in the position where the .bat is called.

How is this possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you meant by concatenating all files?

Comment: With concatenating I mean to take the content of each file and place it in a single file. E.g. if file 1 has the text "abc" and file 2 "def" then the resulting file should have "abc /n def".

Answer (score 1):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /s /b "c:\root\folder\test.log"') do type "%%~fa") > "%~dp0\joined.log"
```

Use `dir` to list the required files, and for each file in the list, type it and send all the output to a file inside the batch file folder.

Comment: Thank you, but I have more than 100 folders, do I have to list them all? Is it no possible to state that I just want all test.log files inside the folders?

Comment: @DictionaryProver, If you can not indicate where the `test.log` files are, you need to find them. The `dir` command will do exactly this, find the `test.log` files.